# Reasons not to enable shared library support in Cabal

Tags: haskell, dynamic-linking, cabal

I'm looking to install Hubris for a Ruby-to-Haskell bridge.

[Recent install instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493620/hubris-fails-to-install-with-missing-c-libraries-ruby-ruby-ruby) say that I need to enable shared library support in Cabal. Are there reasons why I might not want to do that?

Comment: Build times are longer, since there's one more way to build the libraries. I seem to remember that shared libraries didn't work properly on all systems, no idea whether that's fixed and they now work properly on all major platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason is that when you build binaries using shared Haskell libraries, these are affected by any future breakage of your locally installed Haskell packages. In other words, when you upgrade a library, you will have to either keep the old `.so` files around or rebuild the program. This is the main reason why Debian is not yet providing `-dyn` packages for any library besides the set of boot packages.

(The fact that cabal-install does not uninstall stuff helps here a bit, I guess. But nevertheless I prefer not to worry that doing something with `cabal-install` or in `.cabal` might break existing programs.

Comment: In theory, this problem wouldn't exist if Cabal's default were to use shared libraries?

Comment: No, it is a fundamental issue with how GHC compiles stuff, and how easily a change in one module affects another module.